# Gallery order specified by shortcodes is ignored in gallery function

Tags: gallery, order

I have the following gallery order in a shortcode:

```
[gallery ids="1996,2431,372,447,645,641,647,642,649,643,650,648,653,697,652,390"]
```

And I have this function, which creates a nicer looking gallery:

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'pab_gallery'); 

function pab_gallery($attr) {

    global $post;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        //'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order DESC, ID ASC',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => $orderby) );

    #print_r($attachments);


    $output = '<div class="gallery">';
    $output .= '<ul class="clearfix">';
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, true);
        $output .= sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $link);
    }

    return $output.'</ul></div>';
}
```

I have two problems with this: First of all, the order specified by ID is completely ignored, even though I pass "orderby". Additionally, image#1996 is also not displayed by the function, even though it's attached to the post (which I thought isn't necessary anyway when providing IDs to the short codes).
This is the order I receive from the plugin :

```
Array ( [0] => 2431 [1] => 656 [2] => 652 [3] => 651 [4] => 648 [5] => 650 [6] => 643 [7] => 649 [8] => 642 [9] => 647 [10] => 641 [11] => 645 [12] => 629 [13] => 676 )
```

As you can see it's neither the order I specified using the shortcodes, nor is it in any way ascending or descending.

I want the function to display the IDs in the exact order that they're specified in the shortcodes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.5, the gallery shortcode works a bit differently, the order is embedded within the shortcode itself, in the form of the `ids=` attribute. In your call to `get_posts`, change `orderby` to `post__in`, and pass the ids as `include` argument.

For more specifics, look inside `wp-includes/media.php` at the `gallery_shortcode` function to see how core does it.

Comment: How do I retrieve the IDs from the shortcode?